# Method on generic struct that takes inner type as parameter

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a generic struct `Outer<T>`. There is a method on it which takes inner type as parameter `print(&self, t: T)`. When I am using this method it's generating following error: **expected type parameter `T`, found integer**.

Can't understand why I am getting this error. My understanding was, upon calling this method **T** will morph into inner type.

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Outer<T> {
    b: T,
}

impl<T: Debug> Outer<T> {
    fn new(b: T) -> Outer<T> {
        Outer { b }
    }

    fn print(&self, t: T) {
        println!("{:?}", t);
    }
}

fn test<T: Debug>(t: Outer<T>) {
    let v = 45;
    /* ERROR: expected type parameter `T`, found integer */
    t.print(v);
}

fn main() {
    test::<i32>(Outer::new(32));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what happens if you call `test::<&str>(Outer::new("foo"))` instead. What is `t.print(v)` supposed to do? The argument to `Outer::print` is expected to be a `T` which is `&str` in this case, but you've given it 45, which is decidedly not a `&str`.

You may be familiar with C++, where code like this would work because C++ will not check the validity of function bodies until they are instantiated with concrete types.  In contrast, Rust requires that bodies of generic functions be valid for any possible types to which the bounds successfully apply.

One possible way to handle this would be to require that you can convert the integer 45 to `T`.  To do this, we need to decide what type the integer should have, because there isn't a concrete "some random integer" type.  For example, we might choose `u8` and then do this:

```
fn test<T>(t: Outer<T>)
where
    T: Debug,
    u8: Into<T>,
{
    let v = 45u8;
    t.print(v.into());
}
```

Now we can use any `T` where the bound `u8: Into<T>` holds.  This is true for `i32`, so the code in your question will compile with this change.

You could take it one step further and handle any type that can be *fallibly* converted from `u8` by bounding on `TryInto` instead:

```
fn test<T>(t: Outer<T>) -> Result<(), <u8 as TryInto<T>>::Error>
where
    T: Debug,
    u8: TryInto<T>,
{
    let v = 45u8;
    t.print(v.try_into()?);
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    // Add .unwrap() to handle the potential error.
    test::<i32>(Outer::new(32)).unwrap();
}
```

Notably, this will allow you to use `i8` where the `Into` bound would not, because `u8`'s domain is not a subset of `i8`'s domain.

Comment: Why trait bound doesn't work here? For example, if I do `trait Constraint{}` then `Impl Constraint for i32 {}` and `T: Debug + Constraint`. Shouldn't the compiler infer that type T is going to be i32, as Constraint is only implemented for i32?

Comment: No, `Constraint` can be implemented for other types as well and since that's a possibility the compiler doesn't do that inference. This would also require to know every single type `Constraint` is implemented for across every possible crate, which is just not feasible to check.